# Why am I receiving an oversized record TLS error?

Tags: ssl, go, tls1.2

I'm trying to use [`go-xmpp`](https://github.com/mattn/go-xmpp) to connect to [DuckDuckGo's XMPP services](https://duck.co/blog/post/2/using-pidgin-with-xmpp-jabber).

Below is my test-case:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"

    "github.com/mattn/go-xmpp"
)

const (
    svr = "dukgo.com"
    usr = "testtesttest"
    pwd = "test123"
)

func main() {
    xmpp.DefaultConfig = tls.Config{
        ServerName:         svr,
        InsecureSkipVerify: false,
    }

    options := xmpp.Options{
        Host:     svr,
        User:     usr,
        Password: pwd,
    }

    _, err := options.NewClient()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The `log.Fatal` block is being executed and returns the following error message:

```
2016/08/24 16:32:27 tls: oversized record received with length 28012
exit status 1
```

Googling the error points me towards an identical error in Docker, so that's not exactly helpful.  What does this error mean?  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You're probably not connecting to a TLS server. How is your server configured? Do you need to use StartTLS? Is TLS on a different port? Are you suing TLS at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like the example of the go-xmpp package you are using it expects the port too for the tls.

So with out it will try to connect to the HTTP end point and give you this error. You will see errors like this when the endpoint supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate.

Note that the package you are using also supports No TLS double check DuckGo xmpp requirements and change your code to match them.

Other posts like this

- [tls: oversized record received with length XXXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073179/tls-oversized-record-received-with-length-xxxxx?rq=1)

#### Example

https://github.com/mattn/go-xmpp/blob/master/_example/example.go

```
// Server has the port
var server = flag.String("server", "talk.google.com:443", "server")
var username = flag.String("username", "", "username")
var password = flag.String("password", "", "password")
var status = flag.String("status", "xa", "status")
var statusMessage = flag.String("status-msg", "I for one welcome our new codebot overlords.", "status message")
var notls = flag.Bool("notls", false, "No TLS")
var debug = flag.Bool("debug", false, "debug output")
var session = flag.Bool("session", false, "use server session")

// Omitted code

var talk *xmpp.Client
var err error
options := xmpp.Options{Host: *server,
    User:          *username,
    Password:      *password,
    NoTLS:         *notls,
    Debug:         *debug,
    Session:       *session,
    Status:        *status,
    StatusMessage: *statusMessage,
}

talk, err = options.NewClient()
```